# Find the common ratio of the geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given:
Geometric progression Sum = $S$
First Term = $a$
number of terms = $N + 1$

$$a + aq + aq^2 + ... + aq^N = S$$

So, we need to solve this equation:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^N{q^i} = S/a$$

I need a formula to calculate common ratio $q$.
I think this is hard to do, as we need to solve equation of $N$th degree, but this is kind of a special equation, so, maybe there could be a good solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $|q|<1$ and $N$ is large then you can use $(1-q)^{-1}\sim S/a$.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a exact formula. I don't know, may be it's not possible.

Comment: @Heghine: I don't think such a formula exists for general $N$. If $q^{N+1}$ is small enough, you can use the above hint and the answer will be very close.

Comment: Yes, but in my case $q$ may have any real value, so, it's not small enough.

Comment: Can you tell us where this problem showed up?

Answer (score 2):

The $N$-th partial sum is
$$
S_N = a \sum_{k=0}^N q^k = \left\{ 
\begin{align}
a\frac{q^{N+1} - 1}{q - 1}, \quad q \ne 1 \\
a (N + 1), \quad q = 1
\end{align}\right.
$$

So given a problem instance $(a, S, N)$ the first step is to treat the case $a = 0$ which implies $S=0$. In this case any number will work as value for $q$. For the following we assume $a \ne 0$.

If $a \ne 0$ and $S = 0$ there is no solution $q$. For the following we assume $S \ne 0$ as well.

Next thing would be to check if
$$
S = a (N+1)
$$ 
in this case $q=1$ is the solution. For the following we assume $q \ne 1$ too, having $a \ne 0$, $S \ne 0$, $q \ne 1$ as constraints.

If we still got the case $S = a$, then this would require $q = q^{N + 1}$, which would have $q = 0$ as solution and additionally $q = -1$ in case of odd $N$.

**Looking for Fixed Points**

One method would be to search for a fixed point $q^{*}$ for
$$
f(q) = \frac{a}{S} q^{N+1} + 1 - \frac{a}{S}
$$
which fullfills $f(q^{*}) = q^{*}$.

This version of the original problem is easier to reason with, because one can treat this as the geometric problem of the graph of $f(q) = u \, q^n + v$ (two cases for even and odd exponents $n$, two cases for positive or negative factor $u$) crossing the diagonal line $\mbox{id}(q) = q$.

For odd $N$ the exponent in $f$ is even, we got some parabolic graph which has zero, one or two crossings with $\mbox{id}$ and thus that many solutions.

For even $N$ the exponent is $f$ is odd and for $N \ge 2$ there might be even a third solution.

Comment: The OP is looking for a formula. I don't think this will do.

Comment: I think there is no general one (thanks to Galois).

Comment: Galois proves there is not general solution for polynomials of degree 5 and above but this doesn't mean some don't have formulae. Eg $x^n = b$ has a formula.

Comment: Yes, this is kind of a special case, so, maybe there is a solution to solve this equation.

Comment: I have rewritten it. For $N>4$ I would be surprised if that were a special case. But I am not into Galois theory enough to be able to proof this. Also I don't expect roots for every combination of parameters $(a, N, S)$.

Comment: I think it was Niels-Henrik Abel, not Galois...

Comment: OK, according to Wolfram Alpha the problem instance $(a = 1, N = 5, S = 1/2)$ has no real solution $q$.

Comment: @mvw : It has solution about $-0.7$. Unless you mean $N+1 = 5$, the number of terms. All odd-degree polynomial will have at least one real solution.

Comment: $N$ should be the highest order, one less than the number of additive terms. Need to check later if i made an error.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of terms is $N + 1$ the common ratio satisfies

$S=\frac{a(q^{N+1}-1)}{q-1}$

Your sum has $N+1$ terms.

Comment: Yes, but how you can find common ration from that equation?

Comment: I refer to user88595 answer...